# Custom sorting Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `Datagrid` which has only one column and I want applying a custom sort on it. Currently, When I search the word "Clark", Datagrid displays filtered result as this:

```
David Clark
Clark David
```

But I want to display that item which start with `FilterString` at first row:

```
Clark David
David Clark
```

If user search "David", the result should be:

```
David Clark
Clark David
```

This is my datagrid:

```
<TextBox Name="SearchBox" KeyUp="SearchBox_OnKeyUp" />
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding WordsCollectionView}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And this is my codebehind:

```
string[] words = { "David Clark", "Clark David", "John Smith"};
private string _filterString = "";

private ICollectionView _wordsCollectionView;
public ICollectionView WordsCollectionView
{
    get => _wordsCollectionView;
    set { _wordsCollectionView = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WordsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(words);
        WordsCollectionView.Filter = FilterResult;
        DataContext = this;
}

public string FilterString
{
    get => _filterString;
    set
    {
       _filterString = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
       FilterCollection();
    }
}

public bool FilterResult(object obj)
{
    string str = obj as string;
    return str.Contains(FilterString);
}

private void FilterCollection()
{
    _wordsCollectionView?.Refresh();
}

private void SearchBox_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    FilterString = (sender as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `SortDescriptions` in `CollectionViewSource`?

Comment: In my scenario, `SortDescription` can't help. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set both filtering and sorting on an `ICollectionView`:

```cs
WordsCollectionView.Filter = FilterResult
WordsCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); //words have no property
```

See [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control) for full details.

Note that this will result in the sorting you want, but for more advanced sorting you should consider having two columns instead of one, one for the first name and one for the last name.

Comment: Excuse me,  I'm not explaining things right. I've edited my question. In the scenario, the `SortDescriptions` can't help. Please read again and edit your answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you cast `WordsCollectionView` to a `ListCollectionView`, you could set its `CustomSort` property to an `IComparer` where you implement your custom sorting logic. Something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WordsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(words);
    WordsCollectionView.Filter = FilterResult;
    var listCollectionView = WordsCollectionView as ListCollectionView;
    if (listCollectionView != null)
        listCollectionView.CustomSort = new CustomSorter(this);
    DataContext = this;
}

private class CustomSorter : IComparer
{
    private readonly MainWindow _window;

    public CustomSorter(MainWindow window)
    {
        _window = window;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int a = x?.ToString().IndexOf(_window.FilterString) ?? -1;
        int b = y?.ToString().IndexOf(_window.FilterString) ?? -1;
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}
```